# Reading to or Writing from mongodb crashes Node App

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my Node Express app, I have these routes:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    Products.find().sort({ 'popularity': 'desc' }).limit(8).exec(function (err, top8) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log(top8);
        res.render('index', { mostPopular: top8 });
    })
});

router.post('/admin', function (req, res) {
    var entry = req.body;
    console.log("ENTRY");
    console.log(entry);
    var product = new Products({
        name: entry.name,
        type: entry.type,
        subType: entry.subType,
        popularity: entry.popularity,
        price: entry.price
    });
    console.log("DB MODEL");
    console.log(product);
    product.save(function (error) {
    if (error) { console.log(error) };
        });

    res.end();
})
```

When either POSTing to `/admin` or simply loading `/`, the page renders `"this page cannot be reached"`. There are no errors in the Node command prompt or from Mongodb, only in Visual Studio do I see

```
The thread 'main thread' (0x1) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[8104] node.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.
```

However, data is being saved to and read from the db, somehow it's crashing the app afterwards without and errors being thrown (I've tried try/except fields)

EDIT: Result of `npm list`

```
├── bcrypt-nodejs@0.0.3
├─┬ body-parser@1.8.4
│ ├── bytes@1.0.0
│ ├── depd@0.4.5
│ ├── iconv-lite@0.4.4
│ ├── media-typer@0.3.0
│ ├─┬ on-finished@2.1.0
│ │ └── ee-first@1.0.5
│ ├── qs@2.2.4
│ ├── raw-body@1.3.0
│ └─┬ type-is@1.5.7
│   └─┬ mime-types@2.0.14
│     └── mime-db@1.12.0
├─┬ cookie-parser@1.3.5
│ ├── cookie@0.1.3
│ └── cookie-signature@1.0.6
├─┬ debug@2.0.0
│ └── ms@0.6.2
├─┬ express@4.9.8
│ ├─┬ accepts@1.1.4
│ │ ├─┬ mime-types@2.0.14
│ │ │ └── mime-db@1.12.0
│ │ └── negotiator@0.4.9
│ ├── cookie@0.1.2
│ ├── cookie-signature@1.0.5
│ ├── depd@0.4.5
│ ├── escape-html@1.0.1
│ ├─┬ etag@1.4.0
│ │ └── crc@3.0.0
│ ├── finalhandler@0.2.0
│ ├── fresh@0.2.4
│ ├── media-typer@0.3.0
│ ├── merge-descriptors@0.0.2
│ ├── methods@1.1.0
│ ├─┬ on-finished@2.1.1
│ │ └── ee-first@1.1.0
│ ├── parseurl@1.3.1
│ ├── path-to-regexp@0.1.3
│ ├─┬ proxy-addr@1.0.10
│ │ ├── forwarded@0.1.0
│ │ └── ipaddr.js@1.0.5
│ ├── qs@2.2.4
│ ├── range-parser@1.0.3
│ ├─┬ send@0.9.3
│ │ ├── destroy@1.0.3
│ │ ├── mime@1.2.11
│ │ ├── ms@0.6.2
│ │ └─┬ on-finished@2.1.0
│ │   └── ee-first@1.0.5
│ ├── serve-static@1.6.5
│ ├─┬ type-is@1.5.7
│ │ └─┬ mime-types@2.0.14
│ │   └── mime-db@1.12.0
│ ├── utils-merge@1.0.0
│ └── vary@1.0.1
├─┬ jade@1.6.0
│ ├── character-parser@1.2.0
│ ├── commander@2.1.0
│ ├─┬ constantinople@2.0.1
│ │ └─┬ uglify-js@2.4.24
│ │   ├── async@0.2.10
│ │   ├─┬ source-map@0.1.34
│ │   │ └── amdefine@1.0.0
│ │   ├── uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2
│ │   └─┬ yargs@3.5.4
│ │     ├── camelcase@1.2.1
│ │     ├── decamelize@1.2.0
│ │     ├── window-size@0.1.0
│ │     └── wordwrap@0.0.2
│ ├─┬ mkdirp@0.5.1
│ │ └── minimist@0.0.8
│ ├─┬ monocle@1.1.51
│ │ └─┬ readdirp@0.2.5
│ │   └─┬ minimatch@3.0.0
│ │     └─┬ brace-expansion@1.1.3
│ │       ├── balanced-match@0.3.0
│ │       └── concat-map@0.0.1
│ ├─┬ transformers@2.1.0
│ │ ├─┬ css@1.0.8
│ │ │ ├── css-parse@1.0.4
│ │ │ └── css-stringify@1.0.5
│ │ ├─┬ promise@2.0.0
│ │ │ └── is-promise@1.0.1
│ │ └─┬ uglify-js@2.2.5
│ │   ├─┬ optimist@0.3.7
│ │   │ └── wordwrap@0.0.3
│ │   └─┬ source-map@0.1.43
│ │     └── amdefine@1.0.0
│ ├── void-elements@1.0.0
│ └─┬ with@3.0.1
│   └─┬ uglify-js@2.4.24
│     ├── async@0.2.10
│     ├─┬ source-map@0.1.34
│     │ └── amdefine@1.0.0
│     ├── uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2
│     └─┬ yargs@3.5.4
│       ├── camelcase@1.2.1
│       ├── decamelize@1.2.0
│       ├── window-size@0.1.0
│       └── wordwrap@0.0.2
├─┬ mongoose@4.4.10
│ ├── async@1.5.2
│ ├── bson@0.4.21
│ ├── hooks-fixed@1.1.0
│ ├── kareem@1.0.1
│ ├─┬ mongodb@2.1.10
│ │ ├── es6-promise@3.0.2
│ │ ├─┬ mongodb-core@1.3.9
│ │ │ └─┬ require_optional@1.0.0
│ │ │   ├── resolve-from@2.0.0
│ │ │   └── semver@5.1.0
│ │ └─┬ readable-stream@1.0.31
│ │   ├── core-util-is@1.0.2
│ │   ├── inherits@2.0.1
│ │   ├── isarray@0.0.1
│ │   └── string_decoder@0.10.31
│ ├── mpath@0.2.1
│ ├── mpromise@0.5.5
│ ├─┬ mquery@1.10.0
│ │ ├── bluebird@2.10.2
│ │ ├── debug@2.2.0
│ │ └── sliced@0.0.5
│ ├── ms@0.7.1
│ ├── muri@1.1.0
│ ├── regexp-clone@0.0.1
│ └── sliced@1.0.1
├─┬ morgan@1.3.2
│ ├── basic-auth@1.0.0
│ ├── depd@0.4.5
│ └─┬ on-finished@2.1.0
│   └── ee-first@1.0.5
├─┬ passport@0.3.2
│ ├── passport-strategy@1.0.0
│ └── pause@0.0.1
├─┬ serve-favicon@2.1.7
│ ├─┬ etag@1.5.1
│ │ └── crc@3.2.1
│ ├── fresh@0.2.4
│ └── ms@0.6.2
└─┬ stylus@0.42.3
  ├── css-parse@1.7.0
  ├─┬ glob@3.2.11
  │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
  │ └─┬ minimatch@0.3.0
  │   ├── lru-cache@2.7.3
  │   └── sigmund@1.0.1
  ├── mkdirp@0.3.5
  └── sax@0.5.8
```

Comment: This is notably running on windows. How did you install the application dependencies? Can you run an `npm list` inside the application root directory?

Comment: I installed them by adding them to package.json, then clicking install dependencies. Yes, npm list shows all dependencies

Comment: Can you include the output in your question please so we can see it. Remember that console output is "text" so you don't need a screenshot. Just copy and past the "text".

Comment: Do you mean the console.log()s?

Comment: `'npm list` output. Just like was asked originally. The access violation suggests loading an incompatible binary image.

Comment: OK gotcha. I edited with the npm list output

Comment: there is process.on hook for unhandle exception

Comment: Yes I have tried ` process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
    // handle the error safely
    console.log("Uncaught exception: "+err);
    });` but nothing shows up